# Pure Javascript - Turn number into a %

Tags: javascript

My program spits out a number between `0` and `1`, and I cant change that. I need to turn it into a `%` to use as a variable for a CSS selector.

```
<div id="Value">0.50</div>

<script>
var element = document.getElementById("Value");
var percent =  element * 100;
</script>
```

But how am I meant to put a `%` symbol on the end so I can do this:

```
document.getElementById("circle").style.marginLeft = percent;
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `percent + '%'` should do the trick nicely

Comment: also, before using `element` you should extract the content, like `element.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```js
circle.style.marginLeft = Value.innerText*100 + '%'
```

```html
<div id="Value">0.50</div>
<div id="circle">&#9673;<div>
```

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation:

```
document.getElementById("circle").style.marginLeft = percent + "%";
```

Since `"%"` is a string, `percent` will get converted to string and then the result will be the percent value followed by `"%"`.

---

As [Federico pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56127561/pure-javascript-turn-number-into-a/56127603#comment98886655_56127561), you should be using either `.value` (if the `id="Value"` element is a field element [an `input`, `textarea`, or `select`]) or `.textContent` or `.innerHTML` (if it's not). In your case, it's a div, so `textContent` would make sense:

```
var value = document.getElementById("Value").textContent;
var percent = value * 100; // Implicitly converts `value` to number
document.getElementById("circle").style.marginLeft = percent + "%"; // Implicitly converts `percent` to string
```

Comment: No need to assume, it's a `div`, see first line of OP's code.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - I totally missed that he/she had included the markup, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("circle").style.marginLeft = percent + '%';
```

> When used on strings, the + operator is called the concatenation operator.

Reference: [Javascript Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it.

```
document.getElementById("circle").style.marginLeft = percent+"%";
```

In Javascript you can concat natively an int and a string using the '+' operator which means that -

```
var a = 5
var b = a + '%'
```

**result is b = '5%'**

Answer (score 0):

Use innerHTML to get the text from the element

```js
var element = document.getElementById("Value").innerHTML;
var percent =  parseFloat(element)*100;
percent+='%';
console.log(percent)
```

```html
<div id="Value">0.50</div>
```